# How can I access the result from $and and $or condition example on Mongodb site?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I have a question from Mongodb website, the "AND Queries With Multiple Expressions" section(http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/). I try to access the result from the query and it give me undefined. What I did was

```
db.inventory.find( {
    $and : [
        { $or : [ { price : 0.99 }, { price : 1.99 } ] },
        { $or : [ { sale : true }, { qty : { $lt : 20 } } ] }
    ]
} ), function(err, result){
    console.log(result);  undefined
});
```

How can I get the document from result? Thanks!

Comment: Do you find any docs when you query without the whole $and: e.g.  find({} )?

Comment: Edit your question to include a document you "expect" to match the conditions. Then someone can point you to the correct query terms

Comment: Maybe there is no document in you db `db.inventory`.

Comment: try :  db.inventory.find( {.....} , function(err, inventory){console.log(inventory);} );

Answer (score 0):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error );

db.once('open', function() {

#define the collection name specifically    
  var invSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    price: Number,
    sale: Boolean,
    qty: Number
  }, { collection: 'inventory' });

  var Inventory = mongoose.model('Inventory', invSchema);

/* ##create some test data if you wish to try    
  var myInv = new Inventory({ name: 'test2', price: 0.99, sale: true, qty: 18});
  myInv.save(function(err, myInv) {if (err) return console.error(err);});
  var myInv = new Inventory({ name: 'test2', price: 0.99, sale: true, qty: 22});
  myInv.save(function(err, myInv) {if (err) return console.error(err);});
  var myInv = new Inventory({ name: 'test2', price: 0.99, sale: false, qty: 22});
  myInv.save(function(err, myInv) {if (err) return console.error(err);});
  var myInv = new Inventory({ name: 'test2', price: 1.99, sale: true, qty: 18});
  myInv.save(function(err, myInv) {if (err) return console.error(err);});
  var myInv = new Inventory({ name: 'test2', price: 3, sale: true, qty: 18});
  myInv.save(function(err, myInv) {if (err) return console.error(err);});
*/

## it seems that 'result' as object name won't work, use 'inventory'
  Inventory.find( {
        '$and' : [
            { '$or' : [ { 'price' : 0.99 }, { 'price' : 1.99 } ] },
            { '$or' : [ { 'sale' : true }, { 'qty' : { '$lt' : 20 } } ] }
    ]}, function(err, inventory){

    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.dir(inventory);
  });

}); // end db.once open

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
```

Result:

```
# nodejs test.js 
[ { _id: 55b0b155fefa8cbd7ad07c95,
    name: 'test2',
    price: 0.99,
    sale: true,
    qty: 18,
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 55b0b155fefa8cbd7ad07c96,
    name: 'test2',
    price: 0.99,
    sale: true,
    qty: 22,
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 55b0b155fefa8cbd7ad07c98,
    name: 'test2',
    price: 1.99,
    sale: true,
    qty: 18,
    __v: 0 } ]
```

Comment: I have no idea how this is supposed to help, it isn't even commented to show how you get results and you have placed a lot of your own personal code in as such it is useless.

Comment: Commenting it out doesn't help and makes the code harder to follow, also he is not using mongoose models so you have shown the wrong example